# What units are the settings in the contour extraction tool of QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2

I am using a DEM to develop contours for a project area. I am using Raster>Extraction>Contour to develop the contours. One of the setting relates to the interval between contours. I selected 2 in order to get two foot contours, assuming this in feet.The CRS is EPSG:2260 - NAD83 / New York East (ftUS).

I am using QGIS 2.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: I believe it should take from the CRS, is the DEM in EPSG 2260 or are you reprojecting on the fly?

Comment: Yes I reprojected the DEM to EPSG 2260. I figured it likely grabbed the units for the CRS. I know data from the DEM  isnt perfect, but in some areas it is drastically different from actual conditions.